# добавление картинки через css

Tags: html, css, responsive

у меня есть класс `player`. мне нужно добавить в него иконку `play/pause` через css, но когда я добавляю их становится много,[image: как на этой картинке]

css:

```
.player {
    background-image: url('https://image.flaticon.com/icons/svg/149/149657.svg');
}
```

html:

```
<div class="players">
    <span style="color: #fff;">texttext</span>
    <img src="" onclick="togglePlay(this)" id="button">
</div>
```

js:

```
function togglePlay(video) {
  var audio = document.getElementsByTagName("audio")[0];
  if (audio) {
    if (audio.paused) {
        audio.play();
        document.getElementById("button").src = "https://image.flaticon.com/icons/svg/149/149658.svg";
    } else {
        audio.pause();
        document.getElementById("button").src = "https://image.flaticon.com/icons/svg/149/149657.svg";
    }
  }
}
```

И еще почему-то эта иконка не отображается если текст какой-нибудь не напишу. Как можно сделать чтобы без текста иконка вставлялась и только одна? Спасибо

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Добавьте параметр `background-repeat` в ваш класс:

```
.player {
    background-image: url('https://image.flaticon.com/icons/svg/149/149657.svg');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center center;
}
```

либо используйте сокращенный вариант:

```
.player {
    background: url('https://image.flaticon.com/icons/svg/149/149657.svg') no-repeat center center;
}
```

Для отображения кнопки всегда, задайте ей размеры:

```
.player{
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    background: url('https://image.flaticon.com/icons/svg/149/149657.svg') no-repeat center center;
}
```

**P.S.** Не используйте onClick();

Comment: а как тогда быть  с js кодом? нужно же аудио включать по кнопке? объясните пожалуйста.

Comment: @AsasSas лучше обращаться по селектору, типа `$(".players img").off("click").on("click",function(){ ... });` в голом js не силен